# Sumar elementos selccionados con checkobx en un gridview a un textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Tengo un Gridview donde pose varias columna, la ultima tiene valores numerico mi gridiview pose un checkbox, lo que quiero hacer es al momento de hacer un check en una o varias filas se sumen las cantidades a un texbox, intente de varias forma como veran a bajo pero no he podido conseguirlo,espero que me peudan ayudar

Codigo del boton :

```
Protected Sub BtnAplica_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAplica.Click

    Dim resultado As String
    Dim resultado2 As String
    Dim Seleccion As Boolean = False
    Dim sum As Double = 0




    For Each RW As GridViewRow In Gvcobranzas.Rows

        If CType(RW.Cells(2).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked Then
            If GM.ValidaCliente(TxtBuscarCli.Text) = False Then
            ElseIf GM.ValidaNPago(TxtNuPago.Text) = False Then
                resultado = GM.IsnPago(TxtBuscarCli.Text, dlBnaco.SelectedValue, TxtPagoTotal.Text, TxtNuPago.Text, TxtFePago.Text, TxtFeReg.Text)
                Seleccion = True
                With lberror1
                    .Visible = True
                    .Text = resultado
                End With
                Limpiar()
                CargaGridClientes()
                CargaGridnotascreditos()
            Else
                With lberror1
                    .Visible = True
                    .Text = "Ya existe un numero de pago, no se permiten duplicados"
                End With
                Limpiar()
                CargaGridClientes()
                CargaGridnotascreditos()
            End If

        Else
            With lberror1
                .Visible = True
                .Text = "Favor de seleccionar las factura a pagar"
            End With
            Limpiar()
        End If
    Next
    For Each fila As GridViewRow In GvNotasCredito2.Rows
        Dim NCF As String = fila.Cells(1).Text
        Dim monto As Double = fila.Cells(2).Text
        resultado2 = GM.InsNotaC(NCF, TxtNuPago.Text, monto)
        With lberror0
            .Visible = True
            .Text = resultado2
        End With


    Next
    CargaGridClientes()
    CargaGridnotascreditos()
End Sub
```

intente hacer este metodo pero no me funciona

```
Private Sub SumOpcion2()

   Dim total As Decimal = 0
   For Each row As GridViewRow In Gvcobranzas.Rows
       If CType(row.Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked Then
           Dim x As Decimal = 0
           If Decimal.TryParse(row.Cells(0).Text, x) Then
               total += x
           End If
       End If
   Next
  TxtMonto.Text = total
End Sub
```

incluso intente en el evento CheckBox Changed pero tampoco

```
Protected Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    For Record As Integer = 0 To (Gvcobranzas.Rows.Count - 1)
        CType(Gvcobranzas.Rows(Record).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked = CType(Gvcobranzas.HeaderRow.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked
    Next
    Dim total As Decimal = 0
    For Each row As GridViewRow In Gvcobranzas.Rows
        If CType(row.Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked Then
            Dim x As Decimal = 0
            If Decimal.TryParse(row.Cells(0).Text, x) Then
                total += x
            End If
        End If
    Next
    TxtMonto.Text = total
End Sub
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: podrias aclarar que no funciono en cada uno de los casos?

Comment: en el  metodo me pone un 0 en el textbox, luego en las demas nada sucede.

Comment: debugueaste el metdodo? que paso en el mismo? se ejecuto?

Comment: lo hice, el se ejecuta pero como dije arriba solo me pone el valor de cero, no me suma

Comment: o sea que le metodo se ejecuta, nunca agrega nada a total? puede ser que el error este en el metodo? en como ubicar las filas marcadas?

Comment: lo he modificado con coasa que veo y usando algo de mi cabaeza pero no funciona

Comment: entra adentro del for? entra adentro del primer if? adentro del segundo?

Answer (score 0):

Logre hacerlo por javascript

```
                $(function() {
                     //event handler to the checkbox selection change event
                     $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
                         //variables to store the total price of selected rows
                         //and to hold the reference to the current checkbox control
                         var totalPrice = 0, ctlPrice;
                         //iterate through all the rows of the gridview
                         $('.Gvcobranzas tr').each(function() {
                             //if the checkbox in that rows is checked, add price to our total proce
                             if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked")) {
                                 ctlPrice = $(this).find('[id$= Label3]');
                                 //since it is a currency column, we need to remove the $ sign and then convert it
                                 //to a number before adding it to the total
                                 totalPrice += parseFloat(ctlPrice.text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
                             }
                         });
                         //finally set the total price (rounded to 2 decimals) to the total paragraph control.
                         $('.sum').text("$ " + totalPrice.toFixed(2));
                     });
                 });
```